# List businesses - Google Maps APIs Terms of Service

Tags: google-maps

The website I am working on should keep a list of many businesses located at different cities. I add those business manually into my database, and later need to display them with Google Maps using markers (so the main purpose of the map is to display a list of businesses). The map is public and no fees are charged. I am not retrieving businesses' information from Google. What I do not understand is whether I am allowed to use Google Maps to display a list of businesses or not.

I can not quite understand this point of their ToS

10.2 (b) No Business, Residential, or Telephone Listings Services. You must not display business listings Content in any Maps API Implementation that has the primary purpose of making available business, residential address, or telephone directory listings.

Does this basically say that I can implement a service to list businesses, but I cannot query Google to obtain information about other businesses and add them to my own list?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever go through with using Google Maps? I'd like to point out that AlexC's answer seems logical but they did use the word Content. By their definition, "Content" means any content provided through the Service (whether created by Google or its third party licensors), including map and terrain data, photographic imagery, traffic data, places data (including business listings), or any other content. By what I understand, you're simply not supposed to use their "Content".

Comment: No, I just switched to Leaflet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I am not a lawyer but I have taken a good look at the Google Maps licensing and I would read it the opposite way that you have read it.  I think that displaying business listings on a Google map violates their ToS.

> 10.2 Restrictions on the Types of Applications that You are Permitted to Build with the Maps API(s). Except as explicitly permitted in Section 8 (Licenses from Google to You) or the Maps APIs Documentation, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to) do any of the following:
>
> ....
>
> (b) No Business, Residential, or Telephone Listings Services. You must
>   not display business listings Content in any Maps API Implementation
>   that has the primary purpose of making available business, residential
>   address, or telephone directory listings.

It seems to me the criteria that is being evaluated is the type of service you are offering and if the type of offering is a business listing service (which it sounds like you service is) then you are not allowed to use the Google map API.  This makes sense as it would be hard to differentiate that sort of business listing from the service that Google provide.

However, there are a number of free options you could use to put markers on maps that you should look at which avoid this issue.  These include:

- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)
- [GeoExt](http://geoext.org/)
- [PolyMaps](http://polymaps.org/)
- [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/)

Comment: I concur with this reading. Basically you're setting yourself up as a listings provider in competition with Google, and then using their map. It's not surprising they don't want you to do that.

Comment: I also agree with this interpretation, but I'm confused to how Yelp and Expedia (as examples) are not covered under this clause. What constitutes the "primary purpose of making available business ... listings"?

Answer (score 2):

As you have created your own database I suggest you to create a web service of it and then use that data to display it on map.

Refer this link..This one is the best for your question. It explain each every steps from DB to Google Maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Another thing which you can do is that you can upload the bulk data on Google's Places and then you can use Google's Places API to fetch the data. But one thing which you i would like to point is that if you use Places API then it will provide you maximum 20 results. Refer this links.

[Bulk data upload](https://www.google.com/local/add/g?gl=US&hl=en-US&pli=1#uploadfeed)

Hope this will help you....

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/. Also see the documentation of Places API...

Comment: The question here is not "how to implement it", the question is "may I do that".